# Highlight specific rows of a table on clicking a column value. javascript help needed

Tags: javascript, dom, row, selection, highlight

Is there any way to select particular rows of a table as a variable and then change their styling. For example-:

```
     <a onclick="hl(this)">1,2,5</a>

     <table>
     <tr>
     <tr> <td>.....</td></tr>
     <tr> <td>.....</td></tr>
     <tr> <td>.....</td></tr>
     <tr> <td>.....</td></tr>
     </tr>
     </table>
```

now what the hl function does is when i click on it the rows 1,2 and 5 should get highlighted. What i was thinking that if there is anyway i can use some sort of selection for rows by providing an index like

```
     var m=table.rowIndex[1]
```

or something and then doing

```
     m.style.background="something"
```

then it might work but i have no clue what to do, So please help!

Comment: Adding this as a comment rather than an answer... Take a look at jQuery. It makes tasks like this one super easy!

Comment: using jquery for a task that takes a few bytes of "pure" javascript is an overkill

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass the row numbers as a contents of the a tag:

```
<script>
    function hl(el){

        arr = (el.innerHTML).split(",")

        var t = document.getElementById("tbl")
        for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
            t.rows[arr[i]].style.backgroundColor  ="yellow";
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

and the html

```
<table id="tbl">
    <tr ><td >row 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>row 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>row 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>row 4</td></tr>
</table>
<a href="#" onclick="hl(this)">1,2,3</a>
```

**If you want for your table rows to become clickable** - so not to pass the array but trigger the highlight from clicking- you gotta do this:

js

```
function regEvents(){
    trs = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (var i=0; i<trs.length;i++){
        trs[i].onclick = hilite;
    }
}
function hilite(){
this.style.background = "yellow";
}
```

html

```
<table id="tbl">
    <tr ><td >row 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>row 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>row 3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>row 4</td></tr>
</table>
```

and after your dom loads bind the events - so put this at the end of your html file

```
<script>
regEvents();
</script>
```

Comment: You can add a single listener to the table or tbody rather than one on every row, then then just highlight the one that was clicked on. You can also use a closure to remember the last one highlighted so you can remove the highlight when the next one is clicked.

Comment: Hey Michal, this is the code that looks similar to my problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/zhfvv/

I'd really appreciate it if you could point me out the problem.This just doesn't seem to work at all.

Answer (score 0):

In your example markup, the `table` element is the next sibling after the `a` element. If that's really true, then:

```
function hl(anchor) {
    var table = hl.nextSibling;
    while (table && table.nodeName.toUpperCase() !== "TABLE") {
        table = table.nextSibling;
    }
    if (table) {
        var rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
        rows[0].className += " highlighted";
        rows[1].className += " highlighted";
        rows[4].className += " highlighted";
    }
}
```

...where the class "highlighted" applies the selection styles. This assumes there are no nested tables.

More reading:

- [DOM2 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/)
- [DOM2 HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/)
- [DOM3 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/)

---

FWIW, if you're not already using one, I'd recommend using a good JavaScript library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). They smooth over browsers differences for you and provide a lot of utility functionality.

Answer (score 0):

It is much better to give your functions meaningful names. Also, don't use an A element when a button or some other element is more suited (e.g. a styled span). A's are for navigation (anchors and links), not for doing things.

Here's an example of what you are trying to do using the rowIdex. The removing and adding of highlighting could be put in the same loop, or you could remember the previous highlighted rows in a closure to make it a bit more efficient.

But if you're dealing with less than about 100 rows (or probably way more), it won't make any difference to perceived performance.

```
<script>
function hilightRows(id, rowindexes) {
  var table = document.getElementById(id);
  var rows;

  if (table && rowindexes) {

    // Remove any current highlighting
    for (var j=0, jLen = table.rows.length; j < jLen; j++) {
      table.rows[j].style.backgroundColor = '';
    } 

    // Add new highlighting
    for (var i=0, iLen = rowindexes.length; i<iLen; i++) {
      table.rows[rowindexes[i]].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
  }
}
</script>


<button onclick="hilightRows('t0', [1,2,5])">1, 2, 5</button>       
<button onclick="hilightRows('t0', [3,0])">3, 0</button>       
<button onclick="hilightRows('t0', [])">Remove highlight</button>       

<table id="t0">
  <tr><td>.....
  <tr><td>.....
  <tr><td>.....
  <tr><td>.....
  <tr><td>.....
  <tr><td>.....
  <tr><td>.....
</table>
```

Comment: Hey rob, this is the code that looks similar to my problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/zhfvv/

I'd really appreciate it if you could point me out the problem.This just doesn't seem to work at all.

Answer (score -1):

As Lynch is saying... jquery, especially the function [index](http://api.jquery.com/index/)().

And here it goes (just the general idea)

```
$('#thingtobeclicked').click(function()
{
   $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
   $(this).data('indices').each(function(i){
     $('#myTable tr:nth-child(i)').addClass('selected');
   });
});
```

Hope it helps someone or gets me my 2 rep-points back.. :)

I forgot to say: In order to make this work, you set the indices to be selected on the data field of the thingtobeclicked, as in:

```
<a href='#' id='thingtobeclicked' data-indices='1,3,5'></a>
<table id='myTable'>...
```

Comment: as i am brandnew to stackoverflow, i would like to know the reason for the downvote. i just wanted to provide the additional information to the helpful function, but i am not able to do so in comments yet.

Comment: Answers should be *answers*. This is a comment. You can't *quite* post comments yet, but wait a day or two you and you will be able to. :-)

Comment: Thank you, I guess I'll have to live with the consequences of having done something forbidden ;) the teens, you know...

Comment: LOL Worry not. (You can always delete the answer.) It clearly won't be long *at all* before you get the hang of how things are done here (and hopefully push the boundaries).

Comment: There has to be a gazillion users and you find the time to spot newbies, that's either too great to be true or you're a clever bot. see you around!

Comment: BTW, if you want you 2 rep points back, edit the answer so the down voter can delete the downvode, or delete the answer.